# Group rows based on matching condition from another dataframe

Tags: r, conditional-statements, group

I have a CSV file that look like this:

[image]

I want to group all the values in the name column under the chain column.

So, my final table would look like this:

```
     Acala           Algorand         Algorand-borrowed
1    Acala Dollar    Algodex          Algofi Lend
2    Acala LCDOT     Algofi Lend      Folks Finance
```

I tried to look up how to use group or merge function for this, but I wasn't successful. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's great that you have included the expected output. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Questions should be reproducible. This makes it easy for others to copy data easily so that potential solutions can be verified. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include your data from the output of `dput(your_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dcast(dt, rowid(chain) ~ chain, value.var = "name")[, -1]
```

**Output**

```
          Acala    Algorand Algorand-borrowed
1: Acala Dollar     Algodex       Algofi Lend
2:  Acala LCDOT Algofi Lend     Folks Finance
3:   Acala Swap        <NA>              <NA>
```

**Sample data**

```
dt <- data.frame(
  chain = c(rep(c("Acala", "Algorand", "Algorand-borrowed"), 2), "Acala"),
  name = c("Acala Dollar", "Algodex", "Algofi Lend", "Acala LCDOT", "Algofi Lend", "Folks Finance", "Acala Swap")
)
```